# Flask-SocketIO is Running under Werkzeug How to get server run on eventlet?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, eventlet

I run my app test.py on Win10 in the virtual environment venv

I have installled eventlet

My code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'include_help!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def output():    
    return render_template('part.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def app_connect():
    print('Client connected');
    emit('my_event', {'number': "12345678"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
        socketio.run(app)
```

when I run: "flask run" I get the following result

```
(vfern) C:\Users\ps\Python\fernb>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "test.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
[2020-01-15 18:40:30,941] WARNING in __init__: Flask-SocketIO is Running under Werkzeug, WebSocket is not available.
```

if i run "python test.py" I get:

```
  File "C:\Users\ps\Python\fernb\socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask' from partially initialized module 'flask' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\ps\Python\fernb\vfern\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out that when I have only one foo.py file in my virtual environment the command "python test.py" works and socketio is establisched.
Can anyone explain this?